# How to create a special logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'm trying create a log specifically for logging user account activity. I created this inside the initializer folder:

```
class UserTraceLogger < Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msb)
    "#{timestamp.to_formatted_s(:db)} #{severity} #{msg}\r\n"
  end
end

logfile = File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/user.log", 'a')
userlog = AuditLogger.new(logfile)
userlog.sync = true
```

I would like to be able to then use it in my code with:

```
userlog.info 'my message'
```

Right now I am getting this error message when I start the rails server:

```
config/initializers/usertrace_logger.rb:10:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant AuditLogger (NameError)
```

I'm pretty new to rails. I'm not entirely sure this is the correct way to create a global instance or know what exactly I'm missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean `UserTraceLogger.new(logfile)` instead of `AuditLogger.new(logfile)`?

Otherwise you may be missing `require 'audit_logger'` somewhere.

Comment: I did indeed. Thanks for catching that